# How to set an error message from EditorPart when ApplyChanges returns false?

Tags: c#, web-parts

I'm developing a custom ASP.Net WebPart using the WebPartManager and I'm creating a custom EditorPart too. For its **EditorPart.ApplyChanges** method I set the **return value to false** whenever there is an error.

In the EditorZone I get a standard error message indicating that some error happened to the editor, but I want to change that message.
Is that possible? Something like...

```
 public override bool ApplyChanges()
 {
  try
  {
     // save properties
     return true;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     ErrorMessage = ex.Message; // is there any similar property I can fill?
     return false;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found one solution in [social msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/50a0b18b-375a-4b66-8002-882752268620), but I'm not sure it is correct because it is not very well documented. You have to set the error in the PreRender method, something like this:

```
string _errorMessage;

public override bool ApplyChanges()
{
 try
 {
    // save properties
    return true;
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    _errorMessage = ex.Message; // is there any similar property I can fill?
    return false;
 }
}

protected override OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_errorText))
  {
    this.Zone.ErrorText = string.Format("{0}<br />{1}", this.Zone.ErrorText,
                           _errorText);
  }      
  base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```