# Using ValidationGroup with Sharepoint EditorPart

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have written a Sharepoint 2007 web part which requires validation in both the User form, and the Admin form (EditorPart).

I am using InputFormRegularEdpressionValidator to do the validation like this:

```
tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "myID";

InputFormRegularExpressionValidator validTb = new 
                                 InputFormRegularExpressionValidator();
validTb.ControlToValidate  = tb.ID;
validTb.ValidationExpression = myRegExp;
validTb.ValidationGroup = "AdminInput";

this.Controls.Add(tb);
this.Controls.Add(validTb);
```

I have defined two validation groups - one for the UserInput and the other for AdminInput.  I defined a submit button in the user form, and set this ValidationGroup to UserInput,

However, I can't figure out how to apply the ValidationGroup AdminInput to the Ok and Apply buttons in the Editor part, or otherwise validate these fields.

**How does one trigger validtion of EditorPart fields on clicking Ok/Apply separately from validation of fields in the public facing web part?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case i would suggest use the solution provided in link below

[How to set an error message from EditorPart when ApplyChanges returns false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921491/how-to-set-an-error-message-from-editorpart-when-applychanges-returns-false)

```
string _errorText;

public override bool ApplyChanges()
{


 if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(validTb.Text, myRegExp))
            {
        //write you code here in case of valid input
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
        _errorMessage = "Not A valid String";
                return false; 
            }

}

protected override OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_errorText))
  {
    this.Zone.ErrorText =  _errorText;
  }      
  base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant to link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921491/how-to-set-an-error-message-from-editorpart-when-applychanges-returns-false rather than your blog.  Please edit answer.

Comment: But since the validation is not being triggered (at least as far as I can tell), no error is generated.  The question is about how to trigger validation in the EditorPart, not how to handle the results of the validation.

Comment: My point to say was that you can use return true and false after validation which you can handle in your code and you can use this.Zone.ErrorText ="xyz" to display validation message.

Comment: Yes - I see that, but it doesn't answer the question I asked which is how to trigger the validation in the first place.

Comment: the solution i gave you is a best practice followed everywhere even i follow that too if you don't like it or want to implement it its totally your wish

Comment: No - the solution you gave me is the solution to a different question altogether.  It does not help me trigger validation, only handle the result of an already triggered validation.  Perhaps I don't understand what you are saying - in which case perhaps you can restate your answer in a way that addresses the terms of my question.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer - it makes a bit more sense to me now.  I think you mean that I need to put my validation logic within the ApplyChanges() function - so I do the testing there.  Is that what you mean?  Does that mean ValidationGroups and InputFormValidators are not available in the EditorPart?